# Says address already in use when it is not when trying to establish a websocket connection using Gorilla Websocket

Tags: go, websocket

The websocket connection worked before when the ConnectToServer() looked like the following:

```golang
func (s *SocketClient) ConnectToServer(serverUrl string) (*websocket.Conn, error) {
    // Parse the server URL
    u, err := url.Parse(serverUrl)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }


    // Configure the dialer with the local address
    dialer := &websocket.Dialer{
        HandshakeTimeout: 5 * time.Second, // Adjust the timeout as needed
    }

    // Use the dialer to establish the WebSocket connection
    conn, _, err := dialer.Dial(u.String(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        s.logger.Errorf("Could not connect to WebSocket server: %v", err)
        return nil, err
    }

    return conn, nil
}
```

but after adding NetDial inside dialer to specify the specific local address I want it to connect to it started giving me the following error

```golang
func (s *SocketClient) ConnectToServer(serverURL string) (*websocket.Conn, error) {
    u, err := url.Parse(serverURL)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to parse server URL: %w", err)
    }

    mgmtPort, err := strconv.ParseInt(s.cfg.Server.ManagmentPort, 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to parse management port: %w", err)
    }

    serverIP, portString, err := net.SplitHostPort(s.cfg.Server.Q4netSocketServer)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to split server address and port: %w", err)
    }

    serverPort, err := net.LookupPort("tcp", portString)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to lookup server port: %w", err)
    }

    lAddr := net.TCPAddr{IP: net.ParseIP(s.cfg.Server.ManagmentAddress), Port: int(mgmtPort)}
    rAddr := net.TCPAddr{IP: net.ParseIP(serverIP), Port: serverPort}

    dialContext := func(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
        return net.DialTCP("tcp", &lAddr, &rAddr)
    }

    dialer := &websocket.Dialer{
        HandshakeTimeout: 5 * time.Second,
        NetDial:          dialContext,
    }

    conn, _, err := dialer.Dial(u.String(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to dial server: %w", err)
    }

    return conn, nil
}
```

> {"LEVEL":"FATAL","TIME":"2024-02-06T14:46:40.839+0100","CALLER":"cmd/main.go:150","MESSAGE":"Could not start tcp listner at 127.0.0.1:9899 Error : listen tcp 127.0.0.1:9899: bind: address already in use"}

I would appreciate any hints on what may be causing this or if there is better ways to specify the local address for the websocket connection. I would be more than happy to provide more context if needed.

I already tried checking if the port is being used somewhere before running the code, but that is not the case.